# Why does this Objective C code leak memory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

**UPDATED**

I have this method in Objective C:

```
-(NSDate*)roundTo15:(NSDate*)dateToRound {
    int intervalInMinute = 15;
    // Create a NSDate object and a NSDateComponets object for us to use
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:dateToRound];

    // Extract the number of minutes and find the remainder when divided the time interval
    NSInteger remainder = [dateComponents minute] % intervalInMinute; 
    // gives us the remainder when divided by interval (for example, 25 would be 0, but 23 would give a remainder of 3

    // Round to the nearest 5 minutes (ignoring seconds)
    if (remainder >= intervalInMinute/2) {
        dateToRound = [dateToRound dateByAddingTimeInterval:((intervalInMinute - remainder) * 60)]; // Add the difference
    } else if (remainder > 0 && remainder < intervalInMinute/2) {
        dateToRound = [dateToRound dateByAddingTimeInterval:(remainder * -60)]; // Subtract the difference
    }

    return dateToRound;
}
```

This is how I call the method:

```
item.timestamp = 
    [self roundTo15:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60 * 60]];
```

Instruments says I am leaking a NSDate object when the following line is executed:

```
dateToRound = [dateToRound dateByAddingTimeInterval:(remainder * -60)];
```

So it is my item object I need to update with a new corrected NSDate. I tried by making a roundedDate and returning it like this: `return [roundedDate autorelease];`, but then I got a bad access error.

Comment: @ThomasW what's the point in editing a 3 year old question that is no longer relevant anyway? All you're doing is raising the dead by bumping the question.

Comment: Well... that attempt to "Rollback" didn't work how I expected. :(

Comment: @Fogmeister someone else edited it before me which is how it got my attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `dateToRound` is being passed in as a reference to one object and you are setting it to a reference to a different object. The original object is now abandoned and has been leaked.

You should create a new NSDate * and return it instead of reassigning `dateToRound`.

Sample code:

```
-(NSDate*)roundTo15:(NSDate*)dateToRound {
    int intervalInMinute = 15;
    // Create a NSDate object and a NSDateComponets object for us to use
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:dateToRound];

    // Extract the number of minutes and find the remainder when divided the time interval
    NSInteger remainder = [dateComponents minute] % intervalInMinute; // gives us the remainder when divided by interval (for example, 25 would be 0, but 23 would give a remainder of 3

    // Round to the nearest 5 minutes (ignoring seconds)
    NSDate *roundedDate = nil;
    if (remainder >= intervalInMinute/2) {
        roundedDate = [dateToRound dateByAddingTimeInterval:((intervalInMinute - remainder) * 60)]; // Add the difference
    } else if (remainder > 0 && remainder < intervalInMinute/2) {
        roundedDate = [dateToRound dateByAddingTimeInterval:(remainder * -60)]; // Subtract the difference
    } else {
        roundedDate = [[dateToRound copy] autorelease];
    }

    return roundedDate;
}
```

Comment: Robot K beat me to it. To clarify: it's like that when you're calling -roundTo15:, the NSDate instance that you passed to it was still retained by someone when you pulled the rug out from under it (by assigning it to a new date instance). Robot K is correct - create a new NSDate pointer and return that instead of reassigning dateToRound.

Comment: The problem is not `roundTo15:`; there is no problem with it. The problem is its caller, which is passing in a date object that it owns, then replacing that object with `roundTo15:`'s return value without releasing the previous date (and possibly without retaining the new date either). Consider passing the result of `roundTo15:` to a property setter (`self.myDate = …`) instead of assigning directly to the instance variable (`myDate = …`).

Comment: Could you guys please have a look again, I have updated the question.

Comment: Don't call autorelease on roundedDate. It's already an autoreleased object.

Answer (score -2):

Some class methods may return a *new* object on your behalf. Check the documentation, but my guess is that `dateByAddingTimeInterval` does. That is to say the object returned is not set as `autorelease`. In which case you would need to `release` it yourself.

I have found Instruments to report some things that aren't that intuitive. Don't get me wrong, it's a great tool and awesome that you are using. But even some of the sample code from Apple reports leaks.

Comment: I suggest you review the Cocoa Memory Management Programming Guide. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH Only if the method name begins with `alloc` or `new` or contains `copy` will you get back a new object.

Comment: Thanks for the reference and clarification. I will have to recheck those times I ignored instruments and see if I made a similar mistake.